# 'Tuple' Object is not callable: Module Tkinter, Object Listbox with method curselection. Language: Python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, tuples

Hello Dear Programmers.

I have a "Tuple Object is not callable" Errror and I need your help.

```
File "D:\Miniconda3\envs\ml_env\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "D:\Desktop\Gestion de projet mayadigital\inter_admin.py", line 242, in valider_suppression
for i in self.employes():
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I am creating a small software linked to a database. One of the options allows the admin to delete one or multiple users.

To do this I created a Listbox inside a Tkinter Instance. After the admin selected the users to delete, I want to display the list of theses users for confirmation.

This is where I have my problem:

I need to know which are the item clicked on the Listbox, so I use this method:

```
self.employes=self.liste_employes.curselection()
```

But when I want to use self.employes thanks to the following code, I get the error.

```
 for i in self.employes():
        self.employes_a_supprimer.insert(i, rows[i][1]+' '+rows[i][2])
    self.employes_a_supprimer.pack()
```

This is an extract of my code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Jul 16 21:30:12 2020

@author: cheri
"""
from tkinter import *
import bdd_access as ba

class Interface(Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, fenetre, **kwargs):
        """Initialisation de la fenêtre"""
        Frame.__init__(self, fenetre, width=768, height=576, **kwargs)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH)
        self.menu()
        
    def supprimer(self):
        
        self.destroy_menu()
        rows=ba.liste_employes()
        
        self.tx_selection=Label(self, text="Veuillez choisir le(s) employé(s) à supprimer.")
        self.tx_selection.pack()
        self.liste_employes=Listbox(self,selectmode=BROWSE)
        for i in range (0,len(rows)):
            self.liste_employes.insert(i,rows[i][1]+' '+rows[i][2])
        self.liste_employes.pack()
        
        self.button_valider=Button(self,text="Valider",command=self.valider_suppression)
        self.button_valider.pack()

    def destroy_supprimer(self):
        self.title.destroy()
        self.tx_selection.destroy()
        self.liste_employes.destroy()
        self.button_valider.destroy()
        self.button_annuler.destroy()
        
    def valider_suppression(self):
        self.employes=self.liste_employes.curselection()
        self.destroy_supprimer()
        self.title=Label(self,text="Veuillez confirmer que vous souhaitez bien supprimer les employés suivants:")
        self.title.pack()
        
        self.employes_a_supprimer=Listbox(self, selectmode=SINGLE)
        print(self.employes)
        print(type(self.employes))
        for i in self.employes():
            self.employes_a_supprimer.insert(i, rows[i][1]+' '+rows[i][2])
        self.employes_a_supprimer.pack()
        
        self.button_confirmer=Button(self,text="Confirmer",command=self.suppression_bdd)
        self.button_confirmer.pack()
        
        self.button_retour=Button(self,text="Modifier la selection",command=retour_suppression)
        self.button_retour.pack()
        self.button_annuler=Button(self,text="Annuler l'opération",command=self.valider_supprimer_to_menu)
        self.button_annuler.pack()
    
    
    
    def menu(self):
        # Création de nos widgets        
        self.title = Label(self, text="Bienvenue sur l'interface d'administration, que souhaitez-vous faire?")
        self.title.pack()
        
        
        self.bouton_affichage_logins= Button(self,text="Affichage de tous les logins et mots de passe",command=self.affichage)
        self.bouton_affichage_logins.pack()
        
        self.bouton_ajout=Button(self,text="Ajouter un employé au système",command=self.ajout)
        self.bouton_ajout.pack()
        
        self.bouton_suppression=Button(self,text="Supprimer un employé du système",command=self.supprimer)
        self.bouton_suppression.pack()
        
        self.bouton_changer=Button(self,text="Changer un mot de passe",command=self.changer)
        self.bouton_changer.pack()
        
        self.bouton_quitter = Button(self, text="Quitter", command=self.destroy)
        self.bouton_quitter.pack()
    def destroy_menu(self):
        self.title.destroy()
        self.bouton_affichage_logins.destroy()
        self.bouton_ajout.destroy()
        self.bouton_suppression.destroy()
        self.bouton_changer.destroy()
        self.bouton_quitter.destroy()
```

Yes, this is a french code ;)

**Supprimer=Delete**

**Valider_Suppression=Confirm_suppression**

I hope I've made myself clear enough to be understood

Thanks a lot for the future answers on my post.

Comment: Like the error says, you can't call a tuple. `self.employes` is a tuple, not a function. Perhaps you meant `for i in self.employes:`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is an error in my code I could not see, thanks to @bryan-oakley for his help.

The right piece of code is:

```
for i in self.employes: #Without parenthesis
        self.employes_a_supprimer.insert(i, rows[i][1]+' '+rows[i][2])
    self.employes_a_supprimer.pack()
```

Problem solved !